# Unable to display success message after data is inserted using codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i am having comment section in blog description page.If any user comment on the particular blog not able to display the success message it is redirecting directly to blog page.

Controller:

```
function addcomments()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name','First Name' , 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description');
        if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)   
        {   
        $data['mainpage']='blogs';
        $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
        }
        else
        {

            //insert the user registration details into database
            $data=array(
                'blog_id'=>$this->input->post('bl_id'),
                'first_name'=>$this->input->post('first_name'),
                'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                'description'=>$this->input->post('description'),
                );
            if ($this->blogs_model -> insertcomments($data))
            {
                if ($this->blogs_model->sendEmail($this->input->post('email')))
                {
                    //$this->flash->success('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You are Successfully Registered! Please confirm the mail sent to your Email-ID!!!</div>');
                    redirect("blog");
                }
                else
                {
                    //$this->flash->success('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                    redirect("blog");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                // error
                $this->flash->success('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                redirect('blog');
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: success flash messages are in comment line . why ?

Comment: `flash` is your custom library? because generally, we can set a flash message like this `$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'message');`

Comment: use  $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'message'); to set and echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); to display

Answer (score 2):

To set a flash_session you must do it like this:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');
```

And load the session library

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

> https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Try setting

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('message');
```

in the constructor of the controller the user is being redirected to.

Comment: Not displaying success message

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$this->flash->success` try setting the flash message in session using `$this->session->set_flashdata` before the redirects.

Comment: Not displaying success message

Answer (score 1):

So in the controller you can have in one function :

```
$flash=1;
redirect(base_url()."blog/".$flash);
```

And in the target function you can access the $flash value like this :

```
$flash= $this->uri->segment(3); 
if(!is_numeric($flash))
{
  redirect();       
}else{
   if($flash== 1){

   }
}
```

I put segment(3) because on your example $flash is after 2 dashes. But if you have for example this link structure : **`www.mydomain.com/subdomain/home/index/$flash`** you'll have to use **segment(4)**.

Hope that helps.

Comment: And in the target function you can access the $flash value like this : this function i need to add in view file

Comment: what is $flash=1 what is the use of that

Comment: $flash is a variable.. and u can pass message using $flash variable

Comment: I am not getting the target function it means it should be placed in view file